Laravel/Jetstream Livewire - Unable to find component: [profile.edit-profile-information-form]
I need some help for a Project in Laravel/Jetstream/Livewire.
I've made next installation for : Laravel:10.10 Jetstream:3 Livewire:2.11
In the framework provided, there is a page in :
resources/views/profile/show.blade.php


This contain a directive:
@livewire('profile.update-profile-information-form')


This is working as expected and renders the page:
resources/views/profile/update-profile-information-form.blade.php.


So far so good.
Now, duplicating the :
show.blade.php


, rename it as :
edit.blade.php


, duplicate also :
update-profile-information-form.blade.php 


and rename it to :
edit-profile-information-form.blade.php


...then changing the @livewire directive, inside edit.blade.php, give me next error:
type here

Unable to find component: [profile.edit-profile-information-form]


Much more details:
UserProfileController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\UserProfileController as VendorUserProfileController;

class UserProfileController extends VendorUserProfileController
{
    /**
     * Show the user profile screen.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        return view('profile.show', [
            'request' => $request,
            'user' => $request->user(),
        ]);
    }

    public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        return view('profile.edit', [
            'request' => $request,
            'user' => $request->user(),
        ]);
    }
}


Router jetstream.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\CurrentTeamController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\ApiTokenController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\PrivacyPolicyController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\TeamController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\TermsOfServiceController;
//use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\Livewire\UserProfileController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Controllers\TeamInvitationController;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserProfileController as CustomUserProfileController;

Route::group(['middleware' => config('jetstream.middleware', ['web'])], function () {
    if (Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature()) {
        Route::get('/terms-of-service', [TermsOfServiceController::class, 'show'])->name('terms.show');
        Route::get('/privacy-policy', [PrivacyPolicyController::class, 'show'])->name('policy.show');
    }

    $authMiddleware = config('jetstream.guard')
        ? 'auth:'.config('jetstream.guard')
        : 'auth';

    $authSessionMiddleware = config('jetstream.auth_session', false)
        ? config('jetstream.auth_session')
        : null;

    Route::group(['middleware' => array_values(array_filter([$authMiddleware, $authSessionMiddleware]))], function () {
        // User & Profile...
        Route::get('/user/profile', [CustomUserProfileController::class, 'show'])->name('profile.show');
        Route::get('/user/profile-edit', [CustomUserProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'verified'], function () {
            // API...
            if (Jetstream::hasApiFeatures()) {
                Route::get('/user/api-tokens', [ApiTokenController::class, 'index'])->name('api-tokens.index');
            }

            // Teams...
            if (Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures()) {
                Route::get('/teams/create', [TeamController::class, 'create'])->name('teams.create');
                Route::get('/teams/{team}', [TeamController::class, 'show'])->name('teams.show');
                Route::put('/current-team', [CurrentTeamController::class, 'update'])->name('current-team.update');

                Route::get('/team-invitations/{invitation}', [TeamInvitationController::class, 'accept'])
                    ->middleware(['signed'])
                    ->name('team-invitations.accept');
            }
        });
    });
});


Any idea what to be done ?
I was trying:
php artisan livewire:discover

as well as clear cache & routes, but no results
